# Cakephp 3 HTTP client proxy 400 bad request

Tags: curl, ubuntu-14.04, cakephp-3.0, squid

I am using cakephp 3.3.10 in-built **http-client** for making GET/POST requests to scripts on other server. I want to re-route the requests via a proxy server, so that the requests on the destination server the requests appear to be coming from my proxy server ip address.

For the proxy server, I have set-up a ubuntu 14.04 machine and install **squid** on it. Done with basic setting and tried setting it in browser and its working without any issues.

Now, as per cakephp 3 cookbook, I am using following syntax for my get request using proxy,

```
$http = new Client();
$http->get('http://98:87:76:65/test.php', [], ['proxy' => ['proxy' => '12:23:34:45:3128']
```

This requests is giving 400-bad request error. 
I tried same request using cURL with -x(proxy flag) and it is working without any issues:

```
curl -x 12:23:34:45:3128 http://98:87:76:65/test.php
```

How can I use the proxy settings in cakephp3 http client.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which CakePHP version (last line in `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`) are you using?

Comment: @ndm, it's 3.3.10.

Comment: Try upgrading to at least the latest 3.3.x then, a possibly related problem has been fixed as of 3.3.13: **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/10039**

Comment: Thanks, let me try the upgrade first!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just upgraded cakephp version from 3.3.10 to 3.3.15 (composer update did all the job) and the issues have been **fixed**.

Thanks to @[NDM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1392379/ndm) for the upgrade suggestion.